# How to calculate the throughput usage of AWS EBS volume

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, disk, iostat

We have a hadoop cluster running on AWS EC2 instances.
Configured 16T st1 volume in datanodes for HDFS usage.
We need to understand, what is the maximum throughput we are hitting on this st1 volumes.
Since CloudWatch is covering data on 5 mins interval, the values are being averaged out and cannot be trusted.
I came to know that  'iostat -txm 1' can be used to get the real time usage and make out current throughput. But i am failed to understand how to calculate throughput from this result.
Can some one help here to calculate the throughput using iostat ?